# Creating a table with XSL with the position of row for each element and each childelement (odd even)

Tags: xml, xslt

A client of mine is working with XSLT stylesheets. 
This is not really a problem, but I'm at a point where I get stuck.

I'm trying to create a table. The rows in the table should contain both the parent elements and child elements if there are some. Each (parent and childs) should get its own row.

First, I have solved it using a For-each loop which first goes through the parent elements.
And for the specified parent element with child elements another For-each loop that iterates through the child elements.

Now I have the problem that the position() can not return from the child loop to the parent loop, and I can not determine odd, and even in the rows due to that. Odd and even are determined by "mod 2".

So each second row gets the class odd for css styling.

XML looks like:

```
<note>
  <Parent>
    <Childs/>
    <Value>aaa</Value>
  </Parent>
  <Parent>
    <Childs/>
    <Value>bbb</Value>
  </Parent>
  <Parent>
    <Childs>
      <Value>cc_child</Value>
    </Childs>
    <Value>ccc</Value>
  </Parent>
  <Parent>
    <Childs>
      <Value>dd_child1</Value>
    </Childs>
    <Childs>
      <Value>dd_child2</Value>
    </Childs>
    <Value>dddd</Value>
  </Parent>
  <Parent>
    <Childs/>
    <Value>eee</Value>
  </Parent>
</note>
```

As already mentioned, nested for-each loops are apparently no solution, since I can not return the position from the child  back to the parent loop.

Would be great if someone had a solution or idea for me.

Thanks and regards

Comment: What does your XSLT look like? It's difficult to give you an answer without it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable inside parent for-each with value as position() and use it inside nested loop.

Answer (score 0):

> I have solved it using a For-each loop which first goes through the
>   parent elements. And for the specified parent element with child
>   elements another For-each loop that iterates through the child
>   elements.

If you want the rows to be designated as odd or even regardless of the row source, use a **single** loop that goes through the elements of **both** types.